# How to count number of items in each row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe where there are two columns, List1 and List2.

I need to count number of items in List1 and number of items in List2 separately. The items are of mixed types, separated by a comma and there could be spaces after each item. I am stuck as my data frame has 30k plus rows.

| list1 | list2 |
| --- | --- |
| TR67-03, 67.8976 | 6789, SP2B07RAC804, OP21-358-7659, ATHY476 |
| 63380, N151, 0546R2, 053246R3 | 6874, FBH, 107229, BC0.76, TY-87, LO0.665 |

Result for above example:
List1-6
List2-10

I know len() , shape() will give the rows columns.

Comment: Please provide the DataFrame constructor of your example for clarity, do you have strings?

Comment: Are you looking for per-row counts or a sum over all entries? (That is, should '6789' and '6874' count toward the same value, or do the contibute to different lists?) Do you need to deduplicate? Are any of the items themselves strings which might include ","?

Comment: @SarahMesser : sum of all entries in List1.  "6789" and "6784" are counted in List2. I gave an example of my results would look like. Items are of mixed character, alpha numeric , alpha, numeric, decimals etc. separated by comma. Items themselves should not be having ",", they can have hyphen, "-" or space like 456 ast, rty 6.7,

Answer (score 1):

Assuming strings, you can [`count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html) the number of separators, add 1 and sum:

```
df.apply(lambda s: s.str.count(', ').add(1)).sum()
```

Output:

```
list1     6
list2    10
dtype: int64
```

Reproducible input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'list1': ['TR67-03, 67.8976', '63380, N151, 0546R2, 053246R3'],
                   'list2': ['6789, SP2B07RAC804, OP21-358-7659, ATHY476', '6874, FBH, 107229, BC0.76, TY-87, LO0.665']}
                   })
```

Comment: I frequently found we have a similar way of thinking, are you reading me :o ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the datatype is an object('string'), following code will fetch the count of list1 and list 2 cols:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.str.split(',').str.len())
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `string` as datatype, and the `df` as defined by @mozway. If you want to avoid `df.apply` and have a standalone function you can:

```py
def count_by_column(column: str) -> int:
    return sum([len(x.split(',')) for x in df[column].values])

# count each column
for col in df.columns:
    print(col, count_by_column(column=col))

# yields
list1 6
list2 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the faster `agg` function, and could count the commas plus 1:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['TR67-03, 67.8976', '63380, N151, 0546R2, 053246R3'],
                   'col2': ['6789, SP2B07RAC804, OP21-358-7659, ATHY476, 67.8976', '6874, FBH, 107229, BC0.76, TY-87, LO0.665'],})

func = lambda v: v.count(',') + 1

r = df.agg({'col1' : func,
            'col2' : func,
            })

print(r)
```

```
   col1  col2
0     2     5
1     4     6
```